# Inserting a new row and filling in data to vcells phpExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have the following code that does a great job sending data to excel sheet. In the database I have values under a column say k i have values which are comma separated e.g. alphonce, ochieng, abc, so for each value/word, i want to create a new row so that alphonce is in the new row in a given cell same as ochieng etc, like generated table rows holding the names.

```
    $trd = $this->getRequestedTestsDisplay2($labref);
    $coa_details = $this->getAssayDissSummary($labref);

    $row = 26;
    $worksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($trd); $i++) {
        $col = 1;
        foreach ($coa_details as $coa) {
            if ($coa->test_id == $trd[$i]->test_id) {
                $determined = $coa->determined;
                $remarks = $coa->verdict;
            }
        }


        $worksheet
                ->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col++, $row, $trd[$i]->name)
                ->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col++, $row, $trd[$i]->methods)
                ->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col++, $row, $trd[$i]->compedia);



          $worksheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col++, $row, str_replace(",", "\n", $trd[$i]->specification));



        $worksheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col++, $row, str_replace(",", "\n",$determined)); 



        $worksheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col++, $row, str_replace(",", "\n", $trd[$i]->complies));
        $worksheet->getStyle($col++ . $row)->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
        $worksheet->getRowDimension($row)->setRowHeight(-1);

        $row++;
    }


}
```

Comment: What's the question? Be more specific, what failed, what does not work, what lines are the most important?

Comment: str_replace() the `,` with a `"\n"` before writing it to the cell; set the cell style to `autowrap` and the row height to `-1`

Comment: hello mark, kindly assist using the above code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$myData = "Hello,World";

// Write data to cell A1, replacing comma with a new line character
$worksheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(1, 1, str_replace(",", "\n", $myData));
// Set the cell alignment to wrap the text
$worksheet->getStyle('A1')->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
// Set the row height to automatically adjust to the number of lines
//    of data in the cell
$worksheet->getRowDimension(1)->setRowHeight(-1);
```